Why wasn't Randall Stevens convicted in The Shawshank Redemption
In The Shawshank Redemption (1994), when Red and Andy were talking in the library, it was revealed that neither Andy nor the warden could be convicted of the scams the warden was running; it would be the fictional, on paper only, person: Randall Stevens.
However, we see that authorities come to arrest the warden, and then he puts a bullet in his head. But there are no arrest warrants for the fictional Randall Stevens.
But Randall Stevens was supposed to be the one the authorities were to arrest for the scams the warden had run.
Where am I wrong?

Because Andy has already revealed to the newspapers and thus the authorities that Randall Stevens and the warden are one and the same.
Recall that Andy stole the ledger from the warden's safe (placing dummies in their place) and then mailed the ledger at the bank to, in the script, a newspaper office.

A MAN in shirtsleeves is going through the mail on his desk.
He finds Andy's package, rips it open. Pulls out the black
ledger and files. Scans a cover letter. Holy shit. He dashes
to his door and yanks it open, revealing the words on the
glass: "PORTLAND DAILY BUGLE -- Editor In Chief."


Norton walks slowly toward his office. Dazed. The morning
paper in his hand. He goes wordlessly past the DUTY GUARD into
his office. Shuts the door. Lays the paper on his desk.
The headline reads: "CORRUPTION AND MURDER AT SHAWSHANK."
Below that, the sub-headline: "D.A. Has Ledger. Indictments
Expected." Norton looks up as SIRENS SWELL in the distance




Because Andy has already revealed to the newspapers and thus the authorities that Randall Stevens and the warden are one and the same.... If warden and stevens are revealed to be the same then how is Andy allowed to leave the country and withdraw money in the name of Stevens. Because Stevens is now revealed as you point out. And the newspaper has published it. So people should know the name i believe, and thus the bankers also must know Stevens.



@ApoorvaShukla - This is the 1940s. It would frequently take weeks or even months for banks to be informed by the police and courts about account closures.

@ApoorvaShukla The movie literally shows you Andy closing the bank accounts and then giving the package to mail to the newspaper in the last bank he visits, so BEFORE the scam is exposed. And Andy left the country the same way Red does later on, by illegally crossing the border.

@BCdotWEB yeah you are right. He withdraws money before he posts the mail and therefore he has taken money before getting exposed. Also, as Valorum says, even after the newspapers publish the news, it would take some time for the news to spread and by the time, Andy is out of the country as Stevens. And he's taken out the money before mailing the evidence. Damn I didn't see of that.... .. And when Stevens is out of the country, far away, he would be looked for by the police

RED (V.O.)
The next morning, right about the
time Racquel was spilling her
little secret...
253 INT -- CASCO BANK OF PORTLAND -- MORNING (1966) 253
The door opens. Spit-shined shoes enter. DOLLY the shoes to
the counter.
RED (V.O.) 

...a man nobody ever laid eyes on
before strolled into the Casco Bank
of Portland. Until that moment, he
didn't exist -- except on paper.
FEMALE TELLER (O.S.) 

May I help you?
TILT UP to Andy. Smiling in Norton's gray pinstripe suit.
ANDY 

My name is Peter Stevens.
